# Array and IN operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know if there is a way to check that every item in an array can be found in a sub-select currently I've the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   similarity_values 
WHERE  assemblies[1] IN 
       ( 
              SELECT 200) 
OR     assemblies[2] IN 
       ( 
              SELECT 200)
```

And I'm looking for a away to remove the OR and us just one sub select. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM similarity_values WHERE assemblies[*] IN (SELECT 200)
```

2 Notes:

1. The sub select (SELECT 200) is way more complicated
2. the assemblies array contains up to 15 entries

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the result of the subselect to an array and then use the "overlaps" or "contains" operator

```
where assemblies @> array(select ...)
```

or

```
where assemblies && array(select ...)
```

The difference between those is the handling if the array on the right hand side (the result of your sub-select) returns more than one value. `@>` will only be true if all values from the sub-select are contained in `assemblies`. The `&&` will be true if at least one value is found.

If the sub-select always returns **exactly** one row and one column, you could do the following:

```
where (select ...) = ANY(assemblies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   similarity_values 
WHERE  ( SELECT 200 ) IN 
          ( SELECT id 
            FROM unnest( assemblies ) AS id )
```